# How to view logs for frontend ReactJS on Google App Engine?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I made an application with frontend ReactJS and backend Python, which runs on Google App Engine. When I look at Logs Viewer, I'm able to see the prints from the backend (using "print()"), but not from the frontend (using "console.log()").

I tried as selected resources GAE Application - all_module_id and GAE Application - default service - all_module_id (frontend == default service). I've also tried different Log levels, most notably "any log level". I can see the request logs from the frontend, but that's it. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-application-logs) says that stdout and stderr can be used to write logs so I thought it should be possible to see it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log();` is a javascript command in the browser.  You need to open your browser's developer tools to view the javascript console there.  They will not appear in your App Engine logs.

In Chrome, it's View > Developer > JavaScript Console

Comment: I can see it in my own console. I want to see the output from users. How can I see those?

Comment: You can't see those.  Javascript runs in the client (their browser).  To pass info back to your own logs would require some POST call to one of your URLs